# Why isn't the Blog linked to the OpenID system?

Tags: support, feature-request, status-declined, blog

Despite the art looking similar on the Blog, nothing screams "I'm not really a part of StackExchange" than the lack of OpenID.  Why can't I use it to post instead of handing over my Name/Email every time I'd want to post?

Comment: Well we do try to make it as easy as possible to post any blog posts, but there should be *a* threshold

Comment: Though granted, with OpenID it would allow users to write a blog post, but it would still need the Editors to publish their posts

Comment: @Ivo I'm unsure if Nick's talking about posting comments here or actually posting content to the blargh. Nick, can you clarify?

Comment: @Mana, comments initially (as that's what I would do most often) but ultimately either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

Putting aside the technical limitations listed by Rebecca, Arqade's blog has been deprecated and is now only available in a read-only mode for historical purposes, so having Open ID support is a bit of a moot point at this stage.

For future reference, here's the link: [Arqade's Community Blog](https://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 6):

I would very much like OpenID support on the blog.  I spent a considerable amount of time researching options here.  Existing plugins are either broken or actually manage to create a worse experience for the user instead of a better one.

If I (or anyone) can find a decent, working option, I will happily set it up.

Comment: If only there were websites where programmers and web developers could ask programming and webdev questions :)

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a place to say "I need an OpenId plugin for WordPress - ready, set, start coding!" (;

Answer (score 0):

Rebecca can answer, but OpenID is difficult to integrate with WordPress for some reason.